# How to send Telemetry data from custom end point to azure application insight

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, telemetry

I am working with WPF application with client server architecture we not provide internet for client machines so i implemented application telemetry in client WPF application with custom end point and it will send to our local server (on-premise) now i want to send this telemetry data into azure cloud(server have internet connection)

Comment: removing the workbooks tag, this is about telemetry but doesn't have anything specifically to do with workbooks (you'd use workbooks to *analyze* telemetry, not *send* telemetry)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what language/platform your on-premise server application is written with, you can pick up the corresponding [Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview#get-started) and write custom code [using TelemetryClient to send telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) to application insights.

UPDATE on follow up:
At the client end, you can serialize the whole telemetry object like below and then POST to your custom endpoint.

```
var traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry("test message", SeverityLevel.Critical);
traceTelemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = "test";
var traceTelemetrySerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(traceTelemetry);
```

Then you can deserialize at the service end and then send to AI:

```
var traceTelemetryDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TraceTelemetry>(traceTelemetrySerialized);
telemetryClient.TrackTrace(traceTelemetryDeserialized);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about Transmission class, how its work  https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/BASE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Channel/Transmission.cs

Comment: That is part of Telemetry channel in SDK. It handles transmission of telemetry to the Application Insights service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/telemetry-channels

Comment: check this https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2003 tell u have any idea about to implement this

Comment: No idea about how to use that lower level Transmission class in application code (no public documentation). I would rather prefer TelemetryClient https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics to send log (trace/event/exception/request/dependency etc) to app insights after grabbing the POST body from your custom service request. Straightforward and easy to do than trying to play with lower level SDK class.

Comment: but these method only take few parameters and take other telemetry data from the system so we will loose actual telemetry information and we get server details instead

Comment: I don't think you will lose anything. Check my appended answer above due to limitation in comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220490/discussion-between-krishnendughosh-msft-and-muhammed-afsal).

Comment: please check chat